# Need to write notes to date

Tags: java, calendar

so i have a code for calendar.But i need to do notes to every date i choose,just like here [enter link description here](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/calendar.jsf?tab=organizer&cid=1240955)
A simple window when i click on date when i can write,edit and save notes. Don't know how to do that.
Can anyone help me? Another examples maybe.

```
package calendar;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class Calendar extends JFrame {
  String[] years = { "2012", "2013", "2014" };

  JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(years);

  String[] months = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August",
      "September", "October", "November", "December" };

  JList list = new JList(months);

  JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);

  CalendarModel model = new CalendarModel();

  JTable table = new JTable(model);

  public Calendar() {
    super();

    getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    comboBox.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 30);
    comboBox.setSelectedIndex(0);
    comboBox.addItemListener(new ComboHandler());
    scrollPane.setBounds(200, 10, 150, 100);
    list.setSelectedIndex(3);
    list.addListSelectionListener(new ListHandler());
    table.setBounds(10, 150, 550, 200);
    model.setMonth(comboBox.getSelectedIndex() + 1998, list.getSelectedIndex());
    getContentPane().add(comboBox);
    getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
    table.setGridColor(Color.black);
    table.setShowGrid(true);
    getContentPane().add(table);

    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    setSize(600, 500);
    setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calendar app = new Calendar();
  }
  public class ComboHandler implements ItemListener {
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
      model.setMonth(comboBox.getSelectedIndex() + 1998, list.getSelectedIndex());
      table.repaint();
    }
  }

  public class ListHandler implements ListSelectionListener {
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
      model.setMonth(comboBox.getSelectedIndex() + 1998, list.getSelectedIndex());
      table.repaint();
    }
  }
}
class CalendarModel extends AbstractTableModel {
  String[] days = {  "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun" };

  int[] numDays = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

  String[][] calendar = new String[7][7];

  public CalendarModel() {
    for (int i = 0; i < days.length; ++i)
      calendar[0][i] = days[i];
    for (int i = 1; i < 7; ++i)
      for (int j = 0; j < 7; ++j)
        calendar[i][j] = " ";
  }

  public int getRowCount() {
    return 7;
  }

  public int getColumnCount() {
    return 7;
  }

  public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
    return calendar[row][column];
  }

  public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column) {
    calendar[row][column] = (String) value;
  }

  public void setMonth(int year, int month) {
    for (int i = 1; i < 7; ++i)
      for (int j = 0; j < 7; ++j)
        calendar[i][j] = " ";
    java.util.GregorianCalendar cal = new java.util.GregorianCalendar();
    cal.set(year, month, 1);
    int offset = cal.get(java.util.GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;
    offset += 7;
    int num = daysInMonth(year, month);
    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
      calendar[offset / 7][offset % 7] = Integer.toString(i + 1);
      ++offset;
    }
  }

  public boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
    if (year % 4 == 0)
      return true;
    return false;
  }

  public int daysInMonth(int year, int month) {
    int days = numDays[month];
    if (month == 1 && isLeapYear(year))
      ++days;
    return days;
  }
}
```

Comment: You've put a really small amount of effort. You put in three real sentences, didn't bother to make the link look decent, and just dumped a ton of code at us. Please, try to make an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can read your code, put some effort into your question, and accept the answer if it helped. If it didn't, edit the question and hope people come back to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add the mouse listener and do something like this:

```
 table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

       public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
           JTable clickedTable = (JTable)e.getSource();
           int row = clickedTable.getSelectedRow();
           int col = clickedTable.getSelectedColumn();
           String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(getContentPane(), "message");

           //store data based on row and column
   }
});
```

Or

```
     table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

         public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
           int row = table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
           int col = table.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
           String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(getContentPane(), "message");

           //store data based on row and column
      }
  });
```